# properly use ENV Variables in vue-cli

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, axios

So I'm brand freaking new to Vue-Cli and I'm following a tutorial on using a Vue frontend with a Rails backend. Im configuring Axios to handle my requests.

My problem:

Im trying to set an ENV_VAR on my API_URL constant, at this point when I try to console.log the API_URL I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
at <anonymous>:1:13
```

I have the following to **config/dev.env.js**

```
'use strict'
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const prodEnv = require('./prod.env')

module.exports = merge(prodEnv, {
  NODE_ENV: '"development"',
  ENV_API_URL: '"http://localhost:3000/api/fuzeisp/v1"'
})
```

and I am trying to call that ENV in **src/backend/axios/index.js**
import axios from 'axios'

```
const API_URL = process.env.ENV_API_URL

const securedAxiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_URL,
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application.json'
  }
})
```

I have tried to read the docs, but for some reason i cant make heads or tails of this! any assistance here would be greatly appreciated! Please, If you need more information i would be happy to provide it for you!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using `process.env.NODE_ENV`? Do any environment variables work or do all of them give you that error?

Comment: @RobertMoore i just tried process.env.NODE_ENV and got the same error as above

Comment: Does it happen in both development and production?

Comment: @RobertMoore I dont have it in a production env so I don't believe I an assess that?

Comment: Try running vue run build, and then serving the dist directory and see if you get that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vue cli is using the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to parse `.env` files with their content, adding their content to the `process.env` object. However, these variables will only be available at build-time (since `process.env` is a global property of the node environemnt).

Code at client-side will not have access to the `process` object at all. However, vue cli helps out! It reads `process.env` variables at build time and replaces them with their corresponding values - so you can use them in your client side code. **NOTE:** It only replaces those variables prepended with `VUE_APP_`; e.g. `VUE_APP_BASE_URL=www.myapp.com`.

Read more about it [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables)

Comment: So i just need to prepend my ENV_API_URL to read VUE_APP_ENV_API_URL ?

Comment: That will work yes - the link I posted will explain how to use environment variables in Vue much more detailed than I could do here (with examples)

Comment: Maybe they did not explain it clear enough then! I found it to be very detailed

Answer (score 0):

so I was able to log the output of VUE_APP_ENV_API_URL by adding the following in my `App.vue` file:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  mounted () {
    console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_ENV_API_URL)
  }
}
</script>
```